# How to retain position values of original list after the elements of the list have been sorted into pairs (Python)?

Tags: python, list, indexing, position

```
sample = ['AAAA','CGCG','TTTT','AT$T','ACAC','ATGC','AATA']
Position = [0,    1,     2,     3,      4,     5,     6]
```

I have the above sample with positions associated with each element. I do several steps of filtering, the code of which is given [here.](https://eval.in/662091)

The steps in the elimination are:

```
#If each base is identical to itself eliminate those elements eg. AAAA, TTTT
#If there are more than 2 types of bases (i.e.' conversions'== 1 ) then eliminate those elements eg. ATGC
#Make pairs of all remaining combinations
#If a $ in the pair, then the corresponding base from the other pair is eliminated eg. (CGCG,AT$T) ==> (CGG, ATT) and (ATT, AAA)
#Remove all pairs where one of the elements has all identical bases eg. (ATT,AAA)
```

In the end, I have an output with different combinations of the above as shown below.

```
Final Output [['CGG','ATT'],['CGCG','ACAC'],['CGCG','AATA'],['ATT','ACC']]
```

I need to find a way such that I get the positions of these pairs with respect to the original sample as below.

```
Position = [[1,3],[1,4],[1,6],[3,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the list to a list of tuples first

```
xs = ['AAAA', 'CGCG', 'TTTT', 'AT$T', 'ACAC', 'ATGC', 'AATA']
ys = [(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(xs)]

print(ys)
=> [(0, 'AAAA'), (1, 'CGCG'), (2, 'TTTT'), (3, 'AT$T'), (4, 'ACAC'), (5, 'ATGC'), (6, 'AATA')]
```

Then work with that as your input list instead

Comment: But now I will have to change my entire program here(https://eval.in/662091) to incorporate this. Isn't there a way to just keep a track of it externally without messing with the code?

Comment: @biogeek you should post your program as well. i'll be able to help you better.